# How to extend Dart sockets BroadcastStream buffer size of 1024 bytes?

Tags: dart, sockets

IMPORTANT EDIT

After further investigating, I found out that the packet size is in fact much larger than the stated 1024 bytes, the 1024 bytes were just the limit of the standard out I was using (android studio / flutter).

Some of the packets received are now up to ~27 000 bytes large, however that is nowhere near the actually transmitted size of over 10x that.

I am trying to send singular packets of up to 5 MB in length over a Socket connection in Dart. For this, I am using the following code:

```
Socket socket = await Socket.connect(globals.serverUrl, globals.serverPort);
Stream<Uint8List> stream = socket?.asBroadcastStream();
Uint8List? response = await stream?.first;
String responseString = String.fromCharCodes(response);
```

Note that my Server is running Java while the Client is using Dart.

After sending the data packet from the Server to the Client, it successfully receives the first 1024 bytes exactly of the packet, and the rest is nowhere to be found, even after reading `stream.first` multiple times, they continuously read the newly sent packet and not the remaining bytes of the old packet.

So my question is, how do I require the Socket stream to read ALL bytes of the packet until finished, and not just the first 1024?

EDIT:

The received packet on the client is parsed using:

```
String? decrypt(String cipherText, String keyString) {
  final key = Key.fromUtf8(keyString);
  final iv = IV.fromBase64(cipherText.split(":")[1]);
  final encrypter = Encrypter(AES(key, mode: AESMode.cbc, padding: null));
  final encrypted = Encrypted.fromBase64(cipherText.split(":")[0]);

  final decrypted = encrypter.decrypt(encrypted, iv: iv);

  globals.log.i("DECRYPTED: $decrypted");
  return decrypted;
}
```

The error that I am getting stems from getting the IV, since the message is cut off at 1024 bytes and the ":" appears much later in the String.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more information? I couldn't replicate your limitation here. I created a sample `server.dart` and a `client.dart` file and when I sent a message (1mb) from the server to the client it worked as expected, so maybe is it related to your server?

Comment: So as far as I checked, the issue cannot be with the server, since I checked the whole process with a Java based client before and that worked flawlessly. On the client, I am then parsing the data in some way, I will edit the question to represent that.

Comment: You're right. Dart sockets seems to split your message of 5mb into multiple packets of 1024 bytes, this is why you get only the first 1024 bytes by using the `first` getter: it takes only the first packet.

Comment: @KonstaniusEU If you want nice split data packages, you should not use `Socket` unless you have defined your own protocol on top of this which defines and handles what a "package" means for you. The reason is that TCP does not guarantee that a package are not going to be split into multiple smaller packages. This is a reason why I often use the HTTP(S) protocol instead since it does come with the property of defining what a "package"/request is. Also the easy access to TLS encryption and adding headers are just a bonus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the Dart socket *split messages bigger than 1024 bytes into multiple packets of 1024 bytes*. So there's some approaches you can use to combine them together in the client:

#### By extending `Socket` class

I do not believe this is a right solution:

- Hard to extend since it's a platform implementation (you can see the sdk implementation of *dart:io* almost any class method is **external**).
- Hard to maintain.
- Since it depends on custom platform implementations you need to do it on multiple platforms.
- It's easy to create undocumented memory leaks.

Let me know if you still prefer this approach I'll do a further research.

#### By using `Stream<T>.reduce` function

The problem with this approach in your context is that Sockets do not emit a **done** event when a message is sent by using `socket.write('Your message')`.

So unless you're using a socket to send a single message this function can't help you cause it will return a `Future<T>` that will never complete (only when the socket connection is closed).

#### By emitting a EOF message from the server

This is a solution I found even not so elegant, improvements are welcome.

The idea is to concatenate all client received packets into a single one and stop receiving when a pre-determined termination (EOF) string is received.

##### Implementation

Below is a server implementation that emits a message of 5mb followed by a `message:end` string every time a new client is connected.

```dart
import 'dart:io';

Future<void> main() async {
  final ServerSocket serverSocket =
      await ServerSocket.bind(InternetAddress.anyIPv4, 5050);

  final Stream<Socket> serverStream = serverSocket.asBroadcastStream();

  serverStream.listen((client) async {
    print(
        'New client connected: ${client.address}:${client.port} ${client.done} Remote address: ${client.remoteAddress}');

    const int k1byte = 8;
    const int k2bytes = k1byte * 2;
    const int k1kb = k1byte * 1000;
    const int k1mb = k1kb * 1000;
    const int k5mb = k1mb * 5;

    // Create a 5mb string that follows: '1000.....0001'
    final String k1mbMessage = '1${createStringOf(k5mb - k2bytes, '0')}1';

    client.write(k1mbMessage);
    client.write('message:end');
  });

  print('Listening on: ${serverSocket.address} ${serverSocket.port}');
}

String createStringOf(int size, [String char = ' ']) {
  // https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.3/dart-core/String-class.html it says:
  // > A sequence of UTF-16 code units.
  // And from https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2-for-zos/12?topic=unicode-utfs says:
  // > UTF-16 is based on 16-bit code units. Each character is encoded as at least 2 bytes.
  int dartStringEncodingSize = 2;

  assert(size >= dartStringEncodingSize && size.isEven,
      '''Dart char contains 2 bytes so we can only create Strings (with exact size) of even N bytes''');
  assert(char.length == 1, '''[char] must be a single char String''');

  int charCount = size ~/ dartStringEncodingSize;

  return char * charCount;
}
```

And here we can see a client implementation where we use 'our own reduce' function that combine all packets while the termination string is not found.

```dart
import 'dart:io';

Future<void> main() async {
  final Socket server = await Socket.connect('localhost', 5050);

  final Stream<String> serverSocket =
      server.asBroadcastStream().map(String.fromCharCodes); // Map to String by default

  const kMessageEof = 'message:end';

  String message = '';

  await for (String packet in serverSocket) {
    // If you are using [message] as a List of bytes (Uint8List):
    // message = [...Uint8List.fromList(message), ...Uint8List(packet)]
    message += packet;

    // Do not compare directly packet == kMessageEof
    // cause it can be 'broken' into multiple packets:
    // -> 00000 (packet 1)
    // -> 00000 (packet 2)
    // -> 00mes (packet 3)
    // -> sage: (packet 4)
    // -> end   (packet 5)
    if (message.endsWith(kMessageEof)) {
      // remove termination string
      message = message.replaceRange(
        message.length - kMessageEof.length,
        message.length,
        '',
      );
    }

    print('Received: $message'); // Prints '1000000......0000001'
  }
}
```

You can make it more generic if you want by using an extension:

```dart
import 'dart:io';

/// This was created since the native [reduce] says:
/// > When this stream is done, the returned future is completed with the value at that time.
///
/// The problem is that socket connections does not emits the [done] event after
/// each message but after the socket disconnection.
///
/// So here is a implementation that combines [reduce] and [takeWhile].
extension ReduceWhile<T> on Stream<T> {
  Future<T> reduceWhile({
    required T Function(T previous, T element) combine,
    required bool Function(T) combineWhile,
    T? initialValue,
  }) async {
    T initial = initialValue ?? await first;

    await for (T element in this) {
      initial = combine(initial, element);
      if (!combineWhile(initial)) break;
    }

    return initial;
  }
}

Future<void> main() async {
  final Socket server = await Socket.connect('localhost', 5050);

  final Stream<String> serverSocket =
      server.asBroadcastStream().map(String.fromCharCodes);

  const kMessageEof = 'message:end';

  // Reduce with a condition [combineWhile]
  String message = await serverSocket.reduceWhile(
    combine: (previous, element) => '$previous$element',
    combineWhile: (message) => !message.endsWith(kMessageEof),
  );

  // Remove termination string
  message = message.replaceRange(
    message.length - kMessageEof.length,
    message.length,
    '',
  );

  print('Received: $message');
}
```

Since the socket itself doesn't send the done event the way I found to reduce all packets into a single one was by emitting 'our own done event'.

Comment: Thank you so much, after changing my Java server to print an additional '_' at the end of each packet and parsing the response like https://paste.md-5.net/patavuwama.js based on your example, it works flawlessly!