Not able to parse large JSON response in Flutter
Currently, working on WebSocket in Flutter. After the Client and Server connection was established, I tried to send a list of images with base64Encoded from the Client to the Server but was unable to parse the data from the Server side.
I tried using Isolates in Flutter, for Images with 10-20KB Size was able to parse the data but if it's more than 100KB I'm getting a parsing error.
Got this error from the Server side while parsing the data.
Output of Error:
flutter: Error in parsing : FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)
bgQpQ27iPvAA4GOfWrl69Q5fsNuJDi2WxtUAG8IAACZKivnBUT9KovtKJCVvSssK2phGwISmZJT...
^

flutter: Error in parsing : FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)
LjSgtxK1BSQoEbukA8iDxSN8/uStme7zUz/8gf1qCtUcYYQlS5CXECRwCoGO3+k079g0anRr65e...
^

flutter: Error in parsing : FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)
RjltlneHVEEpAKP7gcYM8HFCgoR4hbUUAEGDCZ5ic1YXV9ksMstttuBGU5KRzE0oypsOy44otpk...
^

flutter: Error in parsing : FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)
eGI0gVu4h5xaVAiEbs8YI95qivFtKdUEpTAngdSZp63cm4UNwy2QevUf4pO7IS9KUxBI9571bRS...
^

flutter: Error in parsing : FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)
KUMDn1qYtLBd5ejULhbbaQ3IbjccA8wadc+IL9VtbMWraLZktuKhIlQ27hE/LtVVf4ubtaoz4eB...
^

flutter: Error in parsing : FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)
+LYH3VAjvW1kV4ZFDLZBkGQe9O2zduhRK8kZEnpS0oTIIweKMgpJk8elJ2UqtF6ldssEJIjil3b...

Parsing using Isolate Code:
class ServerLogsParser {
  final Uint8List buffer;

  String get encodedString => String.fromCharCodes(buffer);

  ServerLogsParser({required this.buffer});

  Future<ServerLogs?> parseInBackground() async {
    final p = ReceivePort();

    await Isolate.spawn(_decodeAndParseJson, p.sendPort);
    final res = await p.first;
    return res is ServerLogs ? res : null;
  }

  Future<void> _decodeAndParseJson(SendPort p) async {
    try {
      final jsonData = jsonDecode(encodedString);
      Isolate.exit(p, ServerLogs.fromMap(jsonData));
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error in parsing : $e");
      Isolate.exit(p, null);
    }
  }
}

Server side code
void handleConnection(Socket socket, Emitter<WebSocketState> emit) async {
    printWarning("Connection from Client: ${socket.remoteAddress}");
    socket.listen((event) async {
      final message = String.fromCharCodes(event);
      printSuccess("text from client: ${message}");
      final serverLogs =
          await ServerLogsParser(buffer: event).parseInBackground();
      if (serverLogs != null) {
        add(UpdateLogsEvent(serverLogs: serverLogs));
        print(serverLogs);
        if (serverLogs.action == ActionEnum.login) {
          add(
            HandleLogin(
              email: serverLogs.data['email'],
              password: serverLogs.data['password'],
              socket: socket,
            ),
          );
        }
      }
    }, onError: (error) {
      printError(error);
      clients.remove(socket);
      socket.close();
    }, onDone: () {
      printWarning("Server left");
      clients.remove(socket);
      socket.close();
    });
  }


Please do not add code or error messages as screenshots. Instead, paste the actual text into your questions. Screenshots are not accessible and we can not try or edit your code to find what is wrong. Please edit your question and replace the screenshots.

Sorry @HolgerJust for the inconvenience, updated the question by replacing the screenshot.

Solved this issue by referring to this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/73216767/12336552
